# Adding class on clicking an item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have am trying to create jQuery code which adds a `active-menu` class to a link whenever I click on it. However I need to check first if it already has the class before adding. I only need the link that was clicked to get the class.

```html
<%= link_to "Testimonials", root_path, class: "nav-link js-nav", :"data-id" => "testimonials" %>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', function() {
  var item = $('.js-nav');
  if (item.hasClass('active-menu')) {
    item.removeClass('active-menu');
  } 
  item.addClass('active-menu');
});
```

I thought this would work but as of now it puts `active-menu` on all the items that has `js-nav`. Again, I only need to add the class if it doesn't have it yet and only need to add on the click item.

Comment: Put the click event on `'.js-nav'` instead of the whole document and add the class to `this` instead of all instances of `'.js-nav'`. `$(document).on` = `$('.js-nav').on`.. `var item = $('.js-nav');` = `var item = $(this);`

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of .js-nav. If item = js-nav then, that's exactly what you are doing. If it does not have it, add it, means, all of the items should have it added, so basically, you can do if it does not have it, add it, instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more simplified solution:

```
        $(document).on('click', '.js-nav', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active-menu");
        });
```

Refer: https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: For some it's removing the class.

Comment: @JamesHedegon you can modify the function to add a class after adding a check

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('click', '.js-nav', function() {//  here $(this) is refering to document
        $(this).addClass('active-menu');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the class on $(this) instead of every element that matches class

Also, add class in the else conditions, otherwise it will add class even after removing it

Like this

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
    var item = $(this);
    if (item.hasClass('active-menu')){
      item.removeClass('active-menu');
    } else{
      item.addClass('active-menu');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `$(this)` to get the currently clicked link and then check `hasClass`. Also, in if condition you are removing it and again adding it, instead you can check if no class present then add it otherwise don't do anything.

Also, add click event handler for `.js-nav` instead of all document

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-nav', function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active-menu')) {
        $(this).addClass('active-menu');
    } 
});
```

Comment: The `if` statement is redundant

Comment: did not understand why it is redundant as i am adding class only if it is not there. Can you please elaborate more